# Kinect v2 with Openni 2 and show with OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: opencv, openni, opencv3.1, kinect-v2

I am a newbie in programming and very much in Computer Vision. I am assigned a project in university to detect objects using the Kinect2 sensor.

I am trying to open Kinect 2 sensor via opencv 3.1.0 with VideoCapture method. I am using device.open (CAP_OPENNI2) method to open the Kinect rgb stream and retrieve it into an OpenCV Mat.

Before this, I have built the OPenNI from the source available on the Occipital's GitHub repo: https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers

It has a Kinect2 driver and I was successful in building the Kinect2.dll binaries.

I then built OpenCV 3.1.0 from source with the flag "WITH_OPENNI2" and linked the Includes and Lib path to the OpenNI 2.2.0.33 I built with Kinect2 driver.

Though the OpenCV build was successful and I had all the binaries, linked it to VS2013 and also the OpenNI binaries, I couldn't still open the Kinect 2 sensor.

Has anybody succeeded in doing so?

Kindly help.

Best Regards,

Gholam
||.

Comment: what is the error you are receiving? i had no trouble getting these working earlier in the year, albeit on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working some time ago - but it was not reproducible.

Did you get any images using the example programs of the Kinect SDK and the OpenNI Viewer?

Take a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/85646/openni-22-kinect-v2-driver/ please. They suggest to use the Microsoft Kinect SDK without OpenNI.